# Can't link .o file on terminal ( Mac OS X 10.9), error : ld: library not found for -lcrt1.10.6.o

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks

I updated my os to mac os X 10.9 this morning, after that the error pops out when I was trying  to use the following code to compile and execute my .f90 file in the TERMINAL.

```
ifort -o test test.f90
```

Anyone knows how to resolve this problem?  Thanks a lot !!!!

Changjun

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue until I reinstalled Xcode's command line tools. Either do it from the preferences in Xcode or from the terminal with this command: xcode-select --install

Answer (score 0):

Just install gcc from your terminal:

> $ brew install gcc49

If the brew command isn't recognized, you have to install [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) first.

Comment: Thanks ! The problem is solved after I updated my command line tools to the latest version (released yesterday).